# When editing an expression in a Watch window, the delete key wipes the whole expression

Tags: visual-studio-code

When editing an expression in a Watch window, the delete key wipes the expression and leaves the `VSCode` in an unstable state.
Is it an issue or I'm missing something? If it's an issue it is unbelievable that nobody has noticed it so far (as if nobody uses the debugger).
This is so annoying that I'm considering switching back to Webstorm/Sublime.

More detailed steps to reproduce:
1. Start debugging session in any (backend or frontend) javascript app and set a breakpoint

2. After execution stops, add anything to the Watch window
3. Try editing the expression in the Watch window; use the 'delete' key while editing
4. Result: instead of a single letter being deleted, the whole expression is deleted from the Watch window, and the `VSCode` is left in a bad state which is reflected in all other expressions being greyed out, i.e. almost invisible

After launching with `code --disable-extensions` the same thing happens (while using a `node.js` application)

Comment: You should probably post this here instead: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues